# what will be modified algorithm if this loss function will be modified?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, adaboost

I have a loss function of AdaBoost and $l(h(x),y)=e^{(-y*h(x))}$  and what will be modified algorithm if we modify loss function to $l(h(x),y)=ln(1+e^{(-y*h(x)})$.

I was not able to find a way to approach this problem. How should I work with it?